# Run html5 video in iPhone by clicking a link which is display:none

Tags: html

I have a link  " watch video " when users click on it, they should be able to see video playing in iPhone and other mobiles player. I had hide the video by using display:none but how I can run the video upon click ?

My code is here

```
<p class="links right_links"><a href="#!" onClick="playVideo();">Watch Video Review!</a>
<script>
    function playVideo(){
        $('#mPlayer').show().play();
       //document.getElementById('mPlayer').play();
      }
 </script>
 <video style="display:none" id="mPlayer" controls width="150" src="/imgs/vidrvws/<%=request.querystring("prod")%>.mp4" poster="inc/vscript/poster.png" height="150"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the DOM element in jQuery by using the .get( 0 ) method passing in the index of the item you want. In your case index of 0 will work fine since you used an ID selector.

Updated: Opps, I forgot to add the .get( 0 ) to the code snippet as described above.

Try this..

`$('#mPlayer').show().get( 0 ).play();` instead.

Comment: I'm already using this $('#mPlayer').show().play();
see this page http://ibcart.com/dev/m_pdescfull.asp?prod=5266B001&G=&catid=

and click on video link.

Comment: This worked great. Is it possible when user press Done with the button. It should hide the video again ?